# how to write with clause using criteria in hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have a query where i used WITH clause to generate results.

```sql
 WITH employee AS (SELECT * FROM Employees)
 SELECT * FROM employee WHERE ID < 20
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Sex = 'M'
```

Could you please any one let me know how to write this query in hibernate using criteria specially when with clause present in query.

Comment: I'm a bit confused at what you're trying to accomplish here. Is the goal to get a result set that has all "male" employees and all employees with an ID less than 20 (regardless of "Sex")?

Comment: i am randomly picked up query i am not concern about the where condition i want to know syntax to write WITH clause in criteria -@aryn.galadar

Answer (score 0):

First, you've dramatically over-complicated your SQL. Here's how your query should look in pure SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE ID < 20 or Sex = 'M'
```

Next, assuming you have a Hibernate entity (let's call it `Employee.java` for now), your HQL equivalent would be:

```
from Employee e where e.id < 20 or e.sex = 'M'
```

To do it with a `Criteria`, you'd do the following:

```
final Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Employee.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(
        Restrictions.lt("id", 20),
        Restrictions.eq("sex", "M")
    )
);
criteria.list();
```

Comment: But we are doing query tuning where we used **WITH**  Clause so i  randomly picked one simple query. I need the syntax how to  write WITH Clause using criteria. Could you please let me know @Dean Clark.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't. Instead, you should create a database View and use that in place of your WITH. Then you can code up a new `Entity` that maps the the database View and use that class for your `Criteria`.